# Switch over the generic type in a generic class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3, switch-statement

I've recently tried to write an extension for the [`Measurement`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurement) type in iOS 10 which **switch-cases over the type of the generic** `UnitType`. What I wanted to do is to specify a different string output on a `UILabel` based on the type of unit. My goal was to **simplify the usage**.

The **solution** I came up with was to **define a method for every type of generic** like so:

```
func localizedDescription(for length: Measurement<UnitLength>) -> String {
    // some code
}

func localizedDescription(for speed: Measurement<UnitSpeed>) -> String {
    // some code
}

// etc.
```

What I really wanted was **something different** though, but I couldn't get it to work. Maybe you can, or it is a restriction of Swift as of now. I've prepared a Swift Playground to explain this in detail.

### Example Playground Code

Here's the code that should replicate the situation:

```
import Foundation

//: Example Classes

class GenericType: NSObject {
    // some code

    var value: Double {
        preconditionFailure("Must be overridden in subclasses.")
    }
}
class GenericSubType1: GenericType {
    override var value: Double { return 5 }
}
class GenericSubType2: GenericType {
    override var value: Double { return 10 }
}

// Note that the class is predefined in a different place, so I can't use the body directly.
class SomeClass<T: GenericType> {
    var valueType: T
    init(valueType: T) {
        self.valueType = valueType
    }
}
```

#### Switch-Case Extension

Here's my first **approach using a switch-case**:

```
//: Switch-Case in Extension

extension SomeClass {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch T.self { // `type(of: T)` doesn't work, `T` does neither
        case is GenericSubType1:
            return "\(valueType.value) times"

        case is GenericSubType2:
            return "\(valueType.value) people"

        default:
            preconditionFailure("Forgot to define a description for generic subclass: \(T.self).")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a **warning** though in the two `case` lines which states:

> Cast from 'T.Type' to unrelated type 'GenericSubType1' always fails

I'm not sure why this is giving me this warning, I'd expect this to work as expected. Can somebody explain me? And also, how would you best solve this kind of thing?

Comment: Also, why don't you declare the `GenericType` as a protocol?

Comment: Cause I wanted to replicate the API interface of the `Measurement` class which is a class, too, not a protocol. So imagine there's some stored properties in the `GenericType` class that is independent of the generic type. I've just edited my question with a hint that there's more to the GenericType. That's also the reason why `GenericType` subclasses `NSObject` what I usually don't do if not needed. But `Measurement` does, too, so ... :)

Answer (score 2):

While writing the question I tried a few other things and could come up with the following solution:

```
//: Multiple Extensions

extension SomeClass where T: GenericSubType1 {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        return "\(valueType.value) times"
    }
}

extension SomeClass where T: GenericSubType2 {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        return "\(valueType.value) people"
    }
}
```

Now when I run the following code the outputs are as expected:

```
SomeClass(valueType: GenericSubType1()).localizedDescription // => "5.0 times"
SomeClass(valueType: GenericSubType2()).localizedDescription // => "10.0 people"
```

This **doesn't involve switch-case**, so if you can get that working, I'd be glad to hear your answers. But this works as an extension, so I wanted to share.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a switch in this case, you have two options:

```
extension SomeClass {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch valueType {
        case is GenericSubType1:
            return "\(valueType.value) times"

        case is GenericSubType2:
            return "\(valueType.value) people"

        default:
            preconditionFailure("Forgot to define a description for generic subclass: \(T.self).")
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
extension SomeClass {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch T.self {
        case is GenericSubType1.Type:
            return "\(valueType.value) times"

        case is GenericSubType2.Type:
            return "\(valueType.value) people"

        default:
            preconditionFailure("Forgot to define a description for generic subclass: \(T.self).")
        }
    }
}
```